# Getting the hours of a duration type cell in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell with a duration type field that is marking 25:30:00. I need to convert this to a decimal type of hours. So I would need 25.5 hours. However I cannot find any way of getting the number of hours from the field. Splitting the string by : does not work in a custom function neither does the function HOUR. So how can I do this.

PD: I've found this question [How do I get the number of days for a duration where the number of hours exceeds 24 in google sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639470/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-for-a-duration-where-the-number-of-hours-exceeds) which seems very close to what I want but I can't figure out how to adapt it to my needs. Any help would be apprecaited.

Comment: I don't understand. How do I do this that you've told me? In javscript, if so could you be more specific? In the google sheet, if so, could you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you!! It worked just fine!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Duration is represented in Google Sheets by a number that measures the duration *in days*. (You can see this by changing the format of a cell with duration to a number.) This is why multiplying it by 24, as pnuts suggested, gives the duration expressed in hours. I'd suggest also using `N` to make the result explicitly a number:

```
=N(A2*24)
```

(Assuming duration is in A2). This should eliminate the need to manually format the output as a number.